# Is it possible to get url of first YouTube video from search?

Tags: c#, url, youtube-api

I'm trying to make an app which will give you the url of the first video that comes up when you search something on youtube.

for example :
you write "c#" into a textbox and it outputs "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GhQdlIFylQ8" (link of the first video that comes up)

This is basically how I want the code to look like :

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    output_textbox.Text = GetUrl(input_textbox);
}

string GetUrl(string input)
{
            // ???
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the documentation of the youtube api.

To solve your problem you can use the code from "Search by keyword" and change the value of the MaxResults variable to 1.

[Youtube Data API .NET Code Samples](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/dotnet)